# Can Google Picker Dialog default to LIST but user can still be able to change to GRID?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-api, google-drive-api, google-picker

This only display the list View but can't be changed to grid. And its default is grid, can the default be list?

```
const sharedDrivesView = new google.picker.DocsView(
  google.picker.ViewId[viewId]
)
  .setMimeTypes(viewMimeTypes)
  .setIncludeFolders(true)
  .setSelectFolderEnabled(true)
  .setEnableDrives(true)
  .setMode(window.google.picker.DocsViewMode.LIST);
```

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of what you see? Based on [The Google Picker API](https://developers.google.com/drive/picker/guides/overview) guide, one of its purposes is to have `A similar look-and-feel to the Google Drive UI`, and the screenshot from it looks like the feature should be available regardless of whether `LIST` or `GRID` has been selected as the [DocsViewMode](https://developers.google.com/drive/picker/reference#docs-view-mode)